# TFS 2017 Update 1 NPM Package Feed - UnAuthorized when publish NPM package

Tags: tfs, npm

I'm following the guidelines for setting up the NPM feed 
and connecting to it.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc

I've also got the '**Auth-Token**' generated as part of the '**Connect to Feed**' dialog and updated my user '***.npmrc***' file with the token following the instructions provided.

My 'NodeJs' is latest version as well.

My OS is : Win7 64x

I want to publish standard NPM packages to TFS to be used for Build as our build system is isolated from internet.

Here is the error I get when I publish a package.

```
C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\project\Node\node_modules\which>npm publ
ish
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish"
npm ERR! node v7.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH

npm ERR! need auth auth required for publishing
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\userAppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-
05-19T20_40_46_348Z-debug.log
```

My config settings:

```
C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\project\Node\node_modules\which>npm conf
ig list
; cli configs
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/4.2.0 node/v7.10.0 win32 x64"

; userconfig C:\Users\user\.npmrc
always-auth = true
registry = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/Project-NuGet/np
m/registry"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\project\Node\node_modules\which
; HOME = C:\Users\user
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Thanks,
Mamrez

Comment: What's the build service account your build agent uses? What's the result if you include .npmrc file to the project and map to the build agent, then specify the working folder that contains .npmrc file. (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-npm)

Comment: the account is domain user account. The problem is the step before being able to use NPM packages in the build task; I cannot publish npm packages into TFS NPM package feed. I followed the instructions for NuGet packages and it went smoothly for NuGet packages. but for NPM it is the issue that I stated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue at my side. Can you share the detailed steps?

Comment: Restarted the developer laptop and tried the steps again; It worked!! and I can publish the NPM packages.

Comment: @Mamrez please post the solution as the answer and mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting the developer laptop and tried the steps in the 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc

again; It worked!! and I can publish the NPM packages